# $0$-dimensional intersection in weighted projective space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, projective-geometry, intersection-theory, projective-varieties

Consider homogeneous polynomials $P_0,P_1,P_2,P_3,P_4,P_5$ of degrees $3,3,2,3,2,1$ over $\mathbb{P}^3$, and the map $\phi:\mathbb{P}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{P} = \mathbb{P}(3,3,2,3,2,1)$ given by
$$
\phi(x) = [P_0(x):\dots:P_5(x)].
$$
Let $X$ be the image of $\phi$. The degree of $X$ with respect to $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}}(3)$ is $27$ (intersection of three cubics in $\mathbb{P}^3$).

Now the image $Y$ of the map $\psi:\mathbb{P}(3,3,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{P}$ given by
$$
\psi(x,y,z) = [x^2:xy:xz:y^2:yz:z^2]
$$
seems to have degree $4$ with respect to $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}}(3)$. I would like to compute the number of points in $X\cap Y$. In a standard projective space this number would be $27\cdot 4$. Dividing by the product of the weights we get $1$ which does not make much sense. However, according to MacAulay2 this number should be $48$.

Does anyone has an idea on where this $48$ is coming from?

Thanks a lot.